# Capture am image from webcam and save

Tags: asp.net, image, save, webcam

Hello guys im trying to save a picture taken from my webcam.
im actually using this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class ImageConversions : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreatePhoto();
    }

    void CreatePhoto()
    {
        try
        {

            string strPhoto = Request.Form["imageData"]; //Get the image from flash file
            byte[] photo = Convert.FromBase64String(strPhoto);



           FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Webcam.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            br.Write(photo);
            br.Flush();
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The application RUNS, i get to see the image , i click the capture button it gives no error till here BUT BUT BUT ... NO IMAGE IS SAVED EITHER  i downloaded the sample from
HERE : http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/38150-Capture-save-images-from-Web-camera.aspx  (check the attachemnt)

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: @Emmanuel N NO errors man .... it runs FINE BUT i cannot get the IMAGE its suppossed to save at C:\\Webcam.jpg

Comment: OH guysss i got the solution :\ u shud only NOT save it on DRIVE C: change the saving path and wi will wrk fine  @ Emmanuel N thks fr ur concern bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article. It works pretty good. But I couldn't work with a custom message when webcam is not attached. It gives a auto generated error message.

[webcamlibrarydotnet](https://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/winfrom-and-csharp-sample-code-and-download)

Answer (score 0):

Change Path.. I also had same problem..
Your C Drive Has security level high,
Change path to "D:\Webcam.jpg" and it will work